# Changing the projection of the output to my OpenLayers click event handler

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, epsg

I've been playing around with the OpenLayers click event handler example, which you can see [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html).
It tell you the coordinates where you have clicked but I am trying to change this to be in decimal degrees, I believe this is `epsg:900913`. I've tried adding in transformation but it seems to have just made them coordinates all messed up

```
var tranlonlat = lonlat.transform(
                      new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                      new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")  
                      );
```

this is the original code:

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
            defaultHandlerOptions: {
                'single': true,
                'double': false,
                'pixelTolerance': 0,
                'stopSingle': false,
                'stopDouble': false
            },

            initialize: function(options) {
                this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                    {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                );
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                    this, arguments
                ); 
                this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                    this, {
                        'click': this.trigger
                    }, this.handlerOptions
                );
            }, 

            trigger: function(e) {
                var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                                          + lonlat.lon + " E");
            }

        });
        var map;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

            var ol_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'} );

        var jpl_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "NASA Global Mosaic",
            "http://t1.hypercube.telascience.org/cgi-bin/landsat7", 
            {layers: "landsat7"});

            jpl_wms.setVisibility(false);

            map.addLayers([ol_wms, jpl_wms]);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            // map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 0);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();

            var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
            map.addControl(click);
            click.activate();

        }
```

Comment: Before and after coords example? In the transform function, I would expect that you list the two coordinate ref systems in from, to order, so shouldn't they be reversed? I don't know the sw, but I may recognize the crs values.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I thought that that order was the only logical way but I must be wrong. Thanks!